# How to change URL into thumbnails

Tags: android

I want to represent links to URL as thumbnails.  Here's the that code I'm currently trying:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ArrayList<String> videoLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
    String links1 = "http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/Harold Kumar 3 Christmas bionic.mp4";

    String links2 = "http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/The Amazing Spiderman bionic.mp4";

    String links3 = "http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/Twilight 4 Breaking Dawn bionic.mp4";
    String links4 = "http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/Harold Kumar 3 Christmas bionic fast.mp4";

    String links5 = "http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/The Amazing Spiderman bionic fast.mp4";

    videoLinks.add(links1);
    videoLinks.add(links2);
    videoLinks.add(links3);
    videoLinks.add(links4);
    videoLinks.add(links5);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, videoLinks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(links1, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}



 }
```

Comment: start by reading the documentation of the classes and methods you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting URL strings as the first parameter value for ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail().

However the documentation states that this string should be a filepath, not an URL.

How about this?

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then set it like this.

```
Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromURL(links1.replace(".mp4", ".jpg").toLowerCase());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Don't forget putting the users-permission internet in your manifest.

You should probably put this in an AsyncTask though. You don't want the UI to freeze when you are connecting to the URL.

Edit:

Never mind checked it. You can get the jpg files.